# SASS :not selector

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a `:not` css selector in SASS mixin but it doesn't do anything:

**Code Snippet:**

```
@mixin dropdown-pos($pos:right) {
  &:not(.notip) {
    @if $comp-tip == true{
      @if $pos == right {
        top:$dropdown-width * -0.6;
        @include tip($pos:$pos);
      }
    }
  }
  &.notip {
    @if $pos == right {
      top: 0;
      left:$dropdown-width * 0.8;
    }
  }
}
```

The `.notip` class is being generated but no CSS is being generated for `:not(.notip)`.

Comment: Make sure you're providing enough code that this will actually compile (missing variables, mixins, etc.).  Also, the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I tried re-creating this, and `.someclass.notip` was being generated for me but `.someclass:not(.notip)` was not, for as long as I did not have the `@mixin tip()` defined. Once I had that, it all worked.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/9775949

```
$dropdown-width: 100px;
$comp-tip: true;

@mixin tip($pos:right) {

}

@mixin dropdown-pos($pos:right) {
  &:not(.notip) {
    @if $comp-tip == true{
      @if $pos == right {
        top:$dropdown-width * -0.6;
        background-color: #f00;
        @include tip($pos:$pos);
      }
    }
  }
  &.notip {
    @if $pos == right {
      top: 0;
      left:$dropdown-width * 0.8;
      background-color: #00f;
    }
  }
}

.someclass { @include dropdown-pos(); }
```

**EDIT:** http://sassmeister.com/ is a good place to debug your SASS because it gives you error messages. `Undefined mixin 'tip'.` it what I get when I remove `@mixin tip($pos:right) { }`